# Mel expression in mule anypoint Studio

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

Is there a MEL expression to find the log level and store it in a string variable. I searched Google but didn't find it. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through MEL, you can access a logger using

```
#[org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(loggerName)]
```

The **Log** interface does not contain any direct method to obtain its level, but you can know if a certain level is active or not. So you can use the following expression to obtain a logger level in MEL:

```
#[log = org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(loggerName); return log.isTraceEnabled() ? "TRACE" : log.isDebugEnabled() ? "DEBUG" : log.isInfoEnabled() ? "INFO" : log.isWarnEnabled() ? "WARN" : log.isErrorEnabled() ? "ERROR" : log.isFatalEnabled() ? "FATAL" : "OFF"]
```

Comment: If I want to take the log level from log 4j properties or log 4j xml will this be used what can I give in the place of log name

Comment: @SatheeshKumar If you want to get the root level, you can try to use **root** as the log name. If you are confortable of using log4j in your application (not thinking to change to another logging mechanism), you can reach the log4j factory directly and obtain the root level using the following expression `#[org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().getLevel().toString()]`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing such thing, for a number of reasons. First there is no such thing as a loglevel but a combinations of log levels for packages or classes and a default log level, then each appender will have a minimum log level too, etc.

Also Mule tipically use SLF4J but not necesarily all code will. To make things complicated, in the soon to be released 3.6 the logging system has changed quite a bit.

If I had to do that I would probably have your log4j.properties as a maven processed resource that had the level set and then also would have a property file that mule should use as a property placeholder that will have the property also set as a processed resource.